# Name of path traced by roots of functions from $R^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is the name of the curve or path traced by the solutions $f(x,y)=0$?

If I have a function $f(x,y)$ that passes through the xy-plane, and the gradient $\nabla f(x,y) \neq \vec{0}$ is non-zero, what is the path defined by the roots $P = \{(x,y) | f(x,y) = 0\}$ called?

If there is a name, does it generalize to higher dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general $f(x,y)=k$ can be called the **level curve at level $k$** of function $f$ (here in the case $k=0$).

A synonymous name is "contour lines" (to be found especially in computer graphics).

The general name in any dimension is **level set**, with the particular name "level surfaces" with 3 variables. For example, the level sets of $f(x,y,z):= x^2+y^2+z^2=k$ are spheres with radii $\sqrt{k}$.

The gradient of $f$ at any point of such a curve is normal to the curve.

Think to level curves in geographical terms either

- as curve of equal height on a map for climbers with, in any point, gradient indicating the direction of the biggest slope.
- or as isobaric lines (lines of equal pressure) on a meteorological map, where the gradients give the wind direction.
- or as isotherms...
- or any other "iso-something"...